# Why is there a loop in the confirm window in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, frontend

Why does the confirm window always reappear immediately after i have selected either ok or cancel? And how can I fix this?

```
    var originalValue = "";
    $("#betreffDropdown").change(function () {
        originalValue = $("#betreffDropdown option:selected").attr("class");
    });

    $('#nachrichtentext').on('blur', function (e) {
        var currentValue = $('#nachrichtentext').val(); 
        if (currentValue !== originalValue) {
            if (confirm('Du hast ungespeicherte Änderungen. Möchtest du diese Speichern?')) {
                update();
            }
            else {
                $('#nachrichtentext').focus();

            }
        } 
    });

    function update() {
        var selectedId = $("#betreffDropdown option:selected").attr("id");
        var message = $("#nachrichtentext").val();
        var subject = $("#betreffDropdown option:selected").val();
        var data = {
            "selectedId": selectedId,
            "newMessage": message,
            "subject": subject
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'updatetemplate/',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",

        })
        window.location.reload()
    }


    var templates = Model.Templates.ToList();
    <select id="betreffDropdown" name="BetreffDropdown">
    <option>Bitte wählen:</option>
    @if (Model.Templates != null)
    {

            foreach (var template in templates.Distinct())
        {
            <option id="@template.Item1" class="@template.Item2">@template.Item3</option>
        }
    }
</select>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateView", "Template", null))
{
    <button>Neu</button>
}

    <textarea  readonly id="nachrichtentext" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>

    <input type="checkbox" id="anpassen" name="Anpassen" disabled>

    <label for="anpassen">Anpassen</label>
    <br />
    <br />
<button id="savebtn" disabled class="disabled-button" onclick="window.location.reload()">Speichern</button>

<button id="deletebtn" class="disabled-button" onclick="window.location.reload()">Löschen</button>
```

This is my code that I use. So I check whether the value of a textarea has been changed or not and if so and the textarea loses focus, a confirmation window appears. Clicking 'Ok' should update the template, otherwise the focus should return to the textarea.

I have found nothing in my research....

Comment: Have you debugged at all? What are the values of `currentValue` and `originalValue` when you set a break point and inspect variables?

Comment: for example currentValue is 'Test3' and originalValue, the Value of the database is 'Test2'

Comment: `confirm()` and `alert()` take the focus, so your `blur` event keeps firing.

Comment: What is `update`? Can you edit your question and make sure the code can be *run*? Include the minimal HTML that is needed...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#nachrichtentext').focus();
}, 0);
```

I have the code in a timout with 0 miliseconds. idk how it works, but it works

Answer (score -2):

without a full functional example is hard to tell.
But here are some possible mistakes:

- multiple inclusion of js. maybe the script doing `$('#nachrichtentext').on('blur',` is being loaded more than once.
- multiple events because of ajax responses. if you have an ajax response doing `$('#nachrichtentext').on('blur',` then it could be possible that the response was given more than once, resulting on multiple equivalent handler functions being triggered in the blur event.
- recursive calls, that `update()` is doing some recursion, triggering blur again either manually or by manipulating the focus on the DOM elements.